# eas build "Duplicate resources"

Tags: build, expo, eas

ERROR:[drawable-mdpi-v4/images_3] /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/res/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/drawable-mdpi/images_3.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/images_3] /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/res/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/drawable-mdpi/images_3.jpg: Resource and asset merger: Duplicate resources

The above error occurs when executing an eas build.

I tried running the command below, but the same error is occurring.

rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*
rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/raw